# Create a proper index for query

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, execution-plan

I have a query that needs to be executed by a maximum of 10 concurrent processes at the same time. Each process must extract one different record from the table.

The result which I'm trying to obtain is that in 1 minute a maximum of 35 tasks are extracted, one by one.

The query is exetued within a transaction on each process.

The query is this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM tasks

WHERE tasks.is_executing = 0
AND tasks.date_executed IS NULL
AND IF(
    (
        SELECT COUNT( T.tasks_id )
        FROM tasks AS T
        WHERE (
            T.date_executed IS NOT NULL
            AND T.date_executed >= SUBTIME( NOW(), '0 0:01:00' )
        )
        OR T.is_executing = 1
    ) < 35, 1, 0
)

ORDER BY tasks.priority DESC, tasks.date_created ASC

LIMIT 1

FOR UPDATE;
```

The problem is that looking at the processes on the database, each query takes 40 to 100 seconds to be executed, all in "Sorting" status.

I created these indexes in the table:

```
is_executing_idx ( `is_executing` ASC )
date_executed_idx ( `date_executed` ASC )
tasks_1_idx ( `date_executed` ASC, `is_executing` ASC )
tasks_2_idx ( `is_sending` ASC, `date_sent` ASC, `priority` DESC, `date_created` ASC )
```

An `EXPLAIN` tells me this:

1. `PRIMARY` `tasks`

   - `type = ref`
   - `possible_keys = is_executing_idx,date_executed_idx,tasks_1_idx,tasks_2_idx`
   - `key = date_executed_idx`
   - `key_len = 5`
   - `ref = const`
   - `rows = 1`
   - `filtered = 50.00`
   - `Extra = Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort`
2. `SUBQUERY` `T`

   - `type = index_merge`
   - `possible_keys = is_executing_idx,date_executed_idx,tasks_1_idx,tasks_2_idx`
   - `key = date_executed_idx,is_executing_idx`
   - `key_len = 5,1`
   - `ref = const`
   - `rows = 2`
   - `filtered = 100.00`
   - `Extra = Using sort_union(date_executed_idx,is_executing_idx); Using where`

Table is InnoDB (MySql database).

I really can't understand why it isn't able to use `tasks_2_idx` index on the `PRIMARY` query.

At the moment, instead of 35 tasks extracted/executed per minute I get 5-6 tasks executed per minute (because each process takes 40-70 seconds to complete the query).

I tried building many different kinds of indexes, specially these two: `tasks_1_idx,tasks_2_idx`, but there's **no way at all** the the query wil use them! Why?

Where am I doing wrong?

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `tasks_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `sender_tasks` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `command_line` longtext,
  `priority` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_executed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_executing` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `person_id_updated` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id_created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tasks_id`),
  KEY `priority` (`priority`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `tasks_template_id` (`tasks_template_id`),
  KEY `person_id_updated` (`person_id_updated`),
  KEY `person_id_created` (`person_id_created`),
  KEY `is_executing_idx` (`is_executing`),
  KEY `date_executed` (`date_executed`),
  KEY `tasks_search_order_1_idx` (`date_executed` ASC,`is_executing` ASC),
  KEY `tasks_search_order_2_idx` (`is_executing` ASC,`date_executed` ASC,`priority` DESC,`date_created` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_person_created_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id_created`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_person_updated_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id_updated`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=271191 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

---

Edit: following the suggestions provided by @yper-trollᵀᴹ these are the results of `EXPLAIN` (using his query of course):

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`id`,`select_type`,`table`,`partitions`,`type`,`possible_keys`,`key`,`key_len`,`ref`,`rows`,`filtered`,`Extra`) VALUES 
(1,'PRIMARY','<derived2>',NULL,'system',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,100.00,'Using filesort'),
(1,'PRIMARY','t',NULL,'ref','is_executing_idx,date_executed,tasks_search_order_1_idx,tasks_search_order_2_idx','date_executed','5','const',1,50.00,'Using index condition; Using where'),
(2,'DERIVED','tasks',NULL,'range','is_executing_idx,date_executed,tasks_search_order_1_idx,tasks_search_order_2_idx','tasks_search_order_2_idx','6',NULL,2,100.00,'Using where; Using index');
```

Hope it's sufficiently clear... I don't know how to get a printable execution plan...

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ sorry it was a typo. Now it's correct

Comment: OK. What is the porimary key of the table? If you provided the output of `show create table tasks;`, it would help.

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ Question modified with CREATE TABLE

Comment: Are you sure the output shows `ASC` and `DESC` in index definitions? (`KEY tasks_search_order_2_idx (is_executing ASC, date_executed ASC,priority DESC,date_created ASC)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I would try:

- the subquery is not correlated so we can convert it from `WHERE` to a derived table (in `FROM`).
- get rid of the `IF`, it's obfuscating a simple condition.
- the `T.date_executed IS NOT NULL` is redundant.
- rewrite the `OR` (I assume that `is_executing` can only take tow values, 0 and 1.
- add an index on `(is_executing, date_executed, priority, date_created)` (by the way, don't bother with `ASC` and `DESC` in index definitions. They are ignored).
  I see you already have it, as `tasks_search_order_2_idx`, that's good.

The query:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM tasks
      WHERE is_executing = 0 AND date_executed >= SUBTIME(NOW(), '00:01:00') 
         OR is_executing = 1
      HAVING COUNT(*) < 35
    )  AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    tasks AS t
WHERE t.is_executing = 0
  AND t.date_executed IS NULL
ORDER BY t.is_executing, t.date_executed, 
         t.priority DESC, t.date_created
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the EXPLAIN tells that it's using Filesort on <derived> table type "system" (filtered 100.00), on PRIMARY table "t" it's still using "date_executed" index instead of tasks_search_order_2_idx (which is included in possible_keys) (filtered 50.00) and the "select_type=DERIVED" "type=range" uses tasks_search_order_2_idx (filtered 100.00). Is that good?

Comment: Can you update teh question and add the new plan? What's the difference in execution times with this query?

Comment: Ok I'll update the question right now. Anyway I'm not able to give any execution time because launching the query manually on the DB it gives me 0.000 to 0.016 seconds of execution, and 0.000 seconds for fetching... I'd need to try to execute the query with the concurrent processes and see how it behaves

Comment: How big is the table? 16 ms doesn't sound bad.

Comment: In fact the query itself is not so long to be executed. The problem is when it's executed within a transaction with 10 processes that execute in the exact same moment. Sometimes I also receive a "1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" error because of this query...

Comment: Table size is 281187 records (in 15 months)

Comment: Slightly modified. Should give you a similar plan. Comment when you try it in your parallle processes test.

Comment: The index is not used, probably because of the alternating index use in the `ORDER BY` (`DESC - ASC`).

Answer (score 0):

Turn it inside out.  Quickly quit if there are "too many" running.  What you have not is repeatedly testing how many are running.  I don't see a simple way to do that without some non-SQL code, so let's work on a Stored Function.  It will either return the top priority task to run (and mark it is grabbed), or return `NULL`:

```
CREATE STORED FUNCTION GetTask() ...
BEGIN
    IF ( (... > 35) OR
         (...) )
    THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        START TRANSACTION;
            SELECT @task_id := task_id
                FROM ...
                WHERE worker_id IS NULL
                ORDER BY priority
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE;   -- To avoid another thread grabbing it
            UPDATE ... SET
                    worker_id = _worker_id,  -- grab it
                    time_started = NOW()
                WHERE task_id = @task_id;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
```

Outside the Function, check for `NULL` and `SLEEP(1)` before trying again:

```
while(true)
{
    $task = query("SELECT GetTask(...)");
    if (isset($task))
    {
        Process($task);
        Release($task);
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```